# ng-highcharts not available

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ng-highcharts' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument

Comment: Are you sure you load the <Script> that includes angular.module('ng-highcharts' ?

Comment: yes man, its my app.js

Comment: Not that your module asks for ng-highcharts I'm saying you need to have loaded the <script> tag in your index.html that defines an angular.module('ng-highcharts' if you don't see this in the network panel response somewhere then you need to load some other script from the library that includes that definition  Also link to the actual module you're trying to include I can point you at what I'm talking about.

Comment: Have you refer to all dependencies like here: http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/Hjdnw/ ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to load the highcharts.js file via

```
     <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
     // or a best way is to copy it in your app directory
     <script src="path/to/highcharts.src.js"></script>
```

then inject it to your app

```
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);
```

Comment: The HighCharts source itself doesn't include anything angular specific, there are third party libs that wrap HighCharts.  Personal experience has been it is easier to write your own directives that use the HighCharts source but it depends on your requirements if that's necessary or a third party solution will do.